# Cloud SQL - Growing each day, but not replicating

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I've had a replica slave set up for about two weeks now. It has been failing replication due to configuration issues, but still growing in the size of the master each day (about 5gb a day).

Until today, binary logs were disabled. And if I go to Monitoring -> slave instance, under Backup Configuration, it says "false".

How do I determine why this is growing each day?

I noticed in monitoring in the InnoDB Pages Read/Write section, there are upticks of Write each day, but no read. But what is it writing to? The DB hasn't changed. and there are no binary logs.

I noticed in the docs, it says "Point-in-time recovery is enabled by default when you create a new Cloud SQL instance."

But there has never been a "Backup" listed in the Operations list on the instance. And when I do `gcloud sql instances describe my-instance`, it's not listed under `backUpConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having could possibly happen due to Point-in-time recovery, it will show an increase to your storage constantly.
There, you will be able to keep automated backups enabled while disabling point-in-time recovery. Once you disable it, the binary logs will be deleted and you will notice an immediate reduction in storage usage.

Here are the steps to disable Point-in-time recovery:

- Select your instance
- Select Backups
- Under Settings, select Edit
- Uncheck box for point-in-time recovery

To add an explanation of Point-in-time recovery, I will add Google Cloud SQL documentation with [Postgres](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/pitr#disk-usage) and [MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/pitr#disk-usage).

It is necessary to archive the WAL files for instances it is enabled on. This archiving is done automatically on the backend and will consume storage space (even if the instance is idle), and, consequently, using this feature would cause an increased storage space on your DB instance.